# Facebook Account Kit SDK gives invalid OAuth 2.0 error

Tags: swift, sdk, oauth-2.0

I have integrated **Account kit sdk** in to my project.

I created the application on facebook development dashboard, enabled Account Kit on it. Got **app-id** and **client access token**.

I added it into **info.plist** file. I am getting this error:

```
[AccountKit][Error]: Invalid OAuth 2.0 Access Token
2016-05-31 02:41:32.191 Chat[2919:563260] [AccountKit][Error]: 

Persisting App Events due to error: 

Error Domain=com.facebook.accountkit:Error Code=200 "(null)" 

UserInfo={com.facebook.accountkit:ErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Invalid OAuth access token., NSUnderlyingError=0x147596a30 

{Error Domain=com.facebook.accountkit:ServerError Code=190 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.accountkit:ErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Invalid OAuth access token.}}}
```

Please need help. Thanks

Comment: Are you able to post any code where you are using this and getting the error?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have the correct settings in info.plist.
I had a similar problem and in my case it was missing a key FacebookAppID

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>{your-app-id}</string> 
<key>AccountKitClientToken</key>
<string>{your-account-kit-client-token}</string>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
     <dict>
         <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
         <array>
             <string>ak{your-app-id}</string>
         </array>
     </dict>
</array>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that initialization response type of `AKFAccountKit` matches with your application dashboard configuration.
It can be:

```
accountKit = [[AKFAccountKit alloc] initWithResponseType:AKFResponseTypeAccessToken];
```

or

```
accountKit = [[AKFAccountKit alloc]initWithResponseType:AKFResponseTypeAuthorizationCode];
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with your configuration. You can file a bug report with Facebook here including your token information: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I had copied the wrong AccountKitClientToken into the Info.plist. Got the right one in there and everything is working now!

Answer (score 0):

You can add your client token using `AKFSettings.setClientToken("MY TOKEN")` and make sure to `import AccountKit` at the top of the file where you call this.